# My filtered array does not output anything. What am I missing?

Tags: vuejs2

I followed the Vue documentation on filtering arrays, but it seems like  I must have missed something.

I am testing an array which has three items with two conditions: a name and a boolean. I wanted to test filtering by making a computed property that only returns the name of an item if the boolean value of that item is true.
I am not getting any output, but I am not getting any errors in the console either, so I am unsure of what the issue is.

```
<div v-for="array in filteredDataTest">
    {{ array.name }}
</div>
```

---

```
data() {
  return {
    testArray: [
      {
        name: 'Bob',
        isTrue: false
      },
      {
        name: 'Mary',
        isTrue: true
      },
      {
        name: 'Paul',
        isTrue: false
      }
    ]
  };
},

computed: {
  filteredDataTest() {
    this.testArray.filter(user => {
      if(user.isTrue) {
        return user
      }
    })
  },
},
```

Comment: `filter(user => user.isTrue)` but actually your code works as it is

Answer (score 0):

You should return within the computed getter method. Otherwise you can't see any result from method.

```
computed: {
  filteredDataTest() {
    return this.testArray.filter(user => user.isTrue);
  },
}
```